# Secuencia de tratamiento de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, consola, python-3.7, depuración

Tengo un pequeño programa el cual modifica la segunda lista sustituyendo cada elemento por una tupla en la que esté el elemento original acompañado del número de veces que aparece en la primera lista.

inputs:  `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 1, 3] b = [2, 3, 5]`
output esperado: `b2 = [(2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 1)]`

```
import number_functions

numbers = [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 8, 2, 1, 5]
counters = [2, 3, 5]
number_functions.count_values(numbers, counters)
print(counters)



  import itertools    
    def numbers_functions(lista1, lista2):  
        lista_vacia = []   
        for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(lista1, lista2, 0):
            suma = i + j  
            lista_vacia.append(suma)
            for i in counters:
                i = (suma, counters)
                c = i.count(numbers)
                a = (i, c)
            return a
```

El problema del código es que únicamente retorna el valor íntegro de `lista2`

Comment: cual es el output de este codigo? por favor añadirlo a la pregunta

Answer (score 4):

El código te estará devolviendo el valor de `lista2` porque lo último que tienes es `print(lista2)`.

Aún así el código devuelve otros errores, como variables que no se han creado (`lista_vacia`, `counters`) y algún otro. Si esto no es problema (porque no está el código completo por ejemplo), igual te sirve simplemente con cambiar `funcion.contar(lista1, lista2)` por `print(funcion.contar(lista1, lista2))` que te devolvería el valor retornado por tu función.

Tal y como lo tenías planteado con `list.count(element)` lo puedes hacer, pero no necesitarías importar `itertools`, con un simple bucle que recorra la segunda lista y cuente las veces que cada elemento aparece en la primera puedes tenerlo:

**Bucle for:**

```
def contar(lista1, lista2):
    lista_vacia = []
    for i in lista2:
        lista_vacia.append((i, lista1.count(i)))
    return lista_vacia
```

Y si prefieres hacerlo con comprensión de listas quedaría así:

**Comprensión de listas:**

```
def contar(lista1, lista2):
    return [(i, lista1.count(i)) for i in lista2]
```

En ambos casos para la entrada

```
lista1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 1, 3]
lista2 = [2, 3, 5]
```

Te devolverá:

```
[(2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 1)]
```

Tu código completo sería así:

```
# Aquí puedes utilizar esta función o cambiarla por la opción del 'Bucle for'
def contar(lista1, lista2):  
    return [(i, lista1.count(i)) for i in lista2]

lista1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 1, 3]
lista2  = [2, 3, 5]

print(contar(lista1, lista2))
```

Comment: Hola Adrián Sanz muchas gracias. Tu comentario me ha servido de mucho, pero me ha surgido una duda y es la siguiente: ¿SE PUEDE USAR EL MÓDULO DE ITERTOOLS PARA TRABAJAR CON LISTAS DE LISTAS O TABLAS?

Comment: Su código proporcionado está bien construido aparentemente, pero en la ejecucion de mi programa sin modificar el archivo main no me retorna el valor esperado sino los elementos de la `lista2`

Comment: He probado las dos maneras (tanto con el bucle como con la comprensión de listas) y ambas me funcionan bien así que el error no debe ser ese.

Comment: El archivo main no puede ser modificado. Por lo tanto, lo que he hecho ha sido, sutituir en el bucle for lista1 y lista2 por los nuevos parametros numbers y counters correspondientemente y me ha devuelto la misma lista que `counters`

Comment: Por ende, en el nuevo post puse el nuevo código modificado y el cual a mi me retorna un error

Comment: El codigo original para la resolucion de dicho problema se encontraba en el nuevo post, pero como fue dado por publicado no se puede acceder al mismo

Comment: Si el archivo main no puede ser modificado (del cual no se habla en ningún momento en la pregunta) deberías especificarlo todo de forma detallada al preguntar, puesto que no podemos hacer suposiciones. Por otro lado, SIEMPRE te va a imprimir la lista2 si no modificas tu main, puesto que tienes un print(counters) al final y 'counters' es tu lista2.

Comment: De todas formas, la solución para que comprendamos lo que quieres es editar tu pregunta y añadir cuantas cosas sean necesarias para que sea entendida, en vez de abrir nuevas preguntas similares. Así evitarás que te las cierren por ser duplicados.